# angular HttpClient Call doesn't work in IE?

Tags: angular, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm trying to make an HTTPClient Call from Angular Plugin for Outlook and i receive this error :

**SEC7123: L’en-tête de demande content-type n’est pas présent dans la liste Access-Control-Allow-Headers.**

Comment: seems like you did not define content type see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618872/angular-6-unable-to-set-content-type-of-http-header-correctly

Comment: the error says that you are using custom http header, and by CORS policy it should be allowed with your backend response